# Strange behaviour when redirecting stdout in C

Tags: c, file, printf, stdout, dup

I'm trying to redirect stdout to a file and then restore it back to original in C, but I'm facing  the following strange issue - the following piece of code succesfully writes 
`in stdout` 
`in stdout` 
in stdout and `in file` in the respective file which is all OK.

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define STDOUT 1
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    printf("in stdout \n");
    int old_out = dup(STDOUT);
    close(STDOUT);
    int fd = open("./redirected",O_CREAT|O_RDWR|O_TRUNC,0777);
    printf("in file \n");
    close(fd);
    dup(old_out);
    printf("in stdout\n");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

However, removing the first row of my main function:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define STDOUT 1
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    int old_out = dup(STDOUT);
    close(STDOUT);
    int fd = open("./redirected",O_CREAT|O_RDWR|O_TRUNC,0777);
    printf("in file \n");
    close(fd);
    dup(old_out);
    printf("in stdout\n");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

leads to 
`in file` 
`in stdout` 
being written on stdout and nothing being written in the file. I wonder how this happened? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Consider using dup2() instead

Comment: Did you know that `<unistd.h>` defines a macro `STDOUT_FILENO`?

Comment: @larsmans, I knew there's such macro, but i thought it's in stdlib.h and when I got a compile error i defined it myself to save some hassle.

Comment: @larsmans, 10x for reminding though. I already changed it now :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a buffering issue. The buffer you write "in file" to isn't flushed before stdout is reinstalled, so the output goes to stdout and not to the file. Adding `fflush(stdout);` fixed it here.