# Confused how stdin, stdout and stderr work

Tags: c, file, stdout, stdin, stderr

I have below program,

```
void Print()
{
    printf("\nCall from Print\n");
}

int main()
{
    FILE * pFile;
    char mystring [100];

    pFile = freopen ("myfile.txt" , "r", stdin);
    if (pFile == NULL)
    {
        perror ("Error opening file");
    }
    else 
    {
        if ( fgets (mystring , 100 , pFile) != NULL )
        {
            freopen("myfile.txt" , "a", stdout);
            Print();
            printf("Here it is\n");
            //puts (mystring);
        }
        fclose(stdout);
        fclose (pFile);

    }
    printf("Hello World\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Now when I am execting the program I can not see the output in console window. All the outputs are redirected into `myfile.txt` file. I want the output should come in both `console` and `myfile.txt` too.

After all that why `printf("Hello World\n")`is not getting printed in console.
How to make it printed in console also?

My am working in windows-7, visual studio-2010

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the

```
freopen("myfile.txt" , "a", stdout);
```

will make your `stdout` output to the file `myfile.txt`
This function will redirect the output from console to the file `myfile.txt`

Even if you use `fclose(stdout);`, this will not back the output of stdout to the console it will only close the `myfile.txt`

refer to the following link for more details [Strange behaviour when redirecting stdout in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779356/strange-behaviour-when-redirecting-stdout-in-c)

in order to get the output in both the console and in the file, You have tokeep the stdout untouch do not reopen it with `freaopen()` and do not close it. and You have to print your message twice in the file and in the stdout

Comment: you have already changed the stdout output and also you have close it.

Comment: @MOHAMMED: My question is why `printf("Hello World\n")` is not getting printed in console

Comment: @RasmiRanjanNayak And my answer is still because you have already changed the stdout output and also you have close then the stdout with fclose(stdout);

Comment: :- Thanks for the update. Just wanted to know how can I resolve this problem. How can I print the output in both console and file too

Comment: @RasmiRanjanNayak The answer now update for the  print the output in both console and file too

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way would be to be more explicit about it, by manually printing to both  `stdout` (the original, to get output to the console) and to your file.

By re-opening `stdout` to point at the file, you remove the connection to the console window, which is why no output appears.

You could also *only* use `stdout`, and use an external tool such as [`tee`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?tee) to duplicate the output into a file.

Comment: :- This can be done with `boost` and `unix`. But how to do with Visual Studio 2010?

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced such requirements once.

I have made one macro for such printing log. That print macro expands in one function which print that message in my log file and stdout or stderr depending upon some control variable setting.

Comment: :- Could you pls expand your comment bit more